# mysql not working with php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, installation, windows-xp

I'm trying to have mySQL work on a windows XP sp3 laptop. I'm using `Apache2, php5` and `mysql`.

From the command prompt, I can enter into the mysql server and start creating database and tables.

In php, everytime I try to run any database action, all script stop.

In the `php.ini`, I did enable the following :

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

I have the following code to test the database:

```
echo '<p>testinp php script</p>'; 


// mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", $pw, $db);

echo 'Still here<br>';

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from test");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
print_r ($row);


echo 'Still here';
```

I don't know why, but I can't get the `"Still here"` message to be shown on screen, the script just top the execution.

I've also enable the port in the firewall with not better result.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the mysqli errors?

Comment: did you restart apache after modifying the php.ini ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not showing us where you have defined your variables for username and password.

if you are certain this extension is active. Use the following:

```
if (class_exists('mysqli')) {
    echo "MySQLi Class Exists";
}
else
{
 echo "MySQLi Class Does Not Exist";
}
```

This can check if you have sucessfully enabled this class, using function_exists will return a false because MySQLi & PDO (for future reference) is class based.

If in doubt that you have configured your MySQLi connection correctly. refer to the manual.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

and last but not least, since you have modified your PHP.ini.. double check the following:

1) Are you sure you have modified the one loaded by apache? 
  - if in doubt.. Use phpinfo to identify the location of php.ini

2) Modifications to php.ini require a restart/reload of apache.. All the time. one of the following: 
*Update: Thought You was on linux until reading the tags*

If using IIS:

Open up your management console and select "restart"

If using XAMPP:

Open up your Management Console For Xampp and stop the service, then start it again.

From Command Line:

`net stop apache2.4`      then     `net start apache2.4`  (Replace 2.4 with your apache version)

Consult the manual for manipulating services from CLi:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc736564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Also, with your `echo` statements.. Since you have two of the same echos, try changing them.. or atleast telling us how many (if any) is visible? it's the first one.. Consult the manual..

If it's your second one...

Consult the manual for your functions:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php   - MySQLi Query

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php - MySQli Fetch Assoc

**Final Update(S):**

Consult the manual also for the MySQLi Error:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

And last but not least... Does the database your connecting too exist?   and the same with that table inside your database schema?

Comment: Thank you, I've tried the suggested code and I got the following message : MySQLi Class Does Not Exist Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\www\test.php on line 36, Ive double check the ini file and everything seams enabled (I did restart Apache)

Comment: You have not properly enabled the class; use Google tutorials on how to do it